# Multiple currency selector: converting the clone price only?

Tags: php, magento, currency, magento-1.8

I allow users to select their own currency to see a product price. But I want them always pay the cart by Base Currency which is Euro.

It is just like this [store](http://www.onlineprinters.fr/Flyers-DIN-A8-with-UV-finishing.htm?websale8=diedruckerei.03-aa&pi=PFUA844&ci=001196), where you can see the currency you select in in parentheses, next to the Base Currency (euro),

[image]

Is it possible to achieve that in Magento 1.8?

This is the code of my currency selector.

```
<?php if($this->getCurrencyCount() > 1): ?>
<div class="form-micro">

    <select onchange="window.location.href=this.value" name="custom-currency-selector" id="custom-currency-selector">
        <?php foreach ($this->getCurrencies() as $_code => $_name): ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $this->getSwitchCurrencyUrl($_code)?>"
            <?php if($_code == $this->getCurrentCurrencyCode()): ?>
                selected="SELECTED"
            <?php endif; ?>>
            <?php echo $_name ?> <?php echo Mage::app()->getLocale()->currency($_code)->getSymbol() ?>
        </option>
        <?php endforeach; ?>

    </select>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

The problem with this is that it changes the Base Currency (euro) that you should pay on checkout to the currency you selected, for instance pounds.

So, I just though whether I can clone the price and the currency selector only converts the clone price without converting the original/ base price (in euro)?

```
<?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product) ?>
<?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product, false, '_clone') ?>
```

Is it possible?